# Remove white space between words in interbase

Tags: sql, interbase

I need to remove all white space between "words" in interbase. Coming from a SQL server background I was assuming (wrongly) that interbase would support a replace function but aparently doesn't. So given a telephone number that may or may not contain white space such as 0117 565 464 how can I match it to an  input string without the spacing?

Edit following comments, it's Interbase XE and when I try to use replace is errors with "unknown function replace"

Comment: What version of Interbase / Firebird do you use? Version 2.1 and newer support `REPLACE` according to the Firebird documentation.

Comment: I thought you said Interbase. I don't see any REPLACE statement in Interbase ver 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interbase supports User Defined Functions (UDF) which are externally programmed functions contained in a DLL. A number of UDFs are included with the Interbase product, although there is not one to remove blanks (or dashes). But, you could write your own and add it. Then you can use it like a SQL statement in Interbase.

Comment: Sounds cool, what language do you writes the function in? Can I use c#?

Comment: The UDFs are all in one or more DLLs and can be written in any language able to create a proper dll. I write mine in Delphi. Those that are included with Interbase are written in some variant of C. Of course it has to be able to run on the platform you intend for it to run on. Then you simply define the UDF and parameters to Interbase. And, yes, it is pretty cool.